# Making two columns having 2 pictures each

Tags: html, css

I know this is a stupid one, but I'm making a meet my team page, and I want to make to columns (each column representing the different departments of the company) and each of these columns would have 2 pictures each. It would have the name of the employee under each photo.

HTML goes like this:

```
<div class="profession">
    <h3>Management</h3>
    <div class="employee">
        <img src="pictures/placeholder.png" alt="">
        <h6>John Doe1</h6>
        <img src="pictures/placeholder.png" alt="">
        <h6>John Doe2</h6>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="profession">
    <h3>Developers</h3>
    <div class="employee">
        <img src="pictures/placeholder.png" alt="">
        <h6>John Doe3</h6>
        <img src="pictures/placeholder.png" alt="">
        <h6>John Doe4</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my question would be how to make this happen in CSS?

Comment: make one div who takes all of that code, then set widths for each one of the divs inside the big one, or use bootstrap, it's way much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple two column layout using Flexbox:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="profession column"><h3>Management</h3>...</div>
    <div class="profession column"><h3>Developers</h3>...</div>
</div>
```

Then in for the CSS:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
}
```